# Visual Studio 2012 cannot be started after an upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I recently upgraded my Windows 7 pro version to a Windows 8 pro version. Everything went smoothly, and all programs and services (including SQL server) are working normaly, except for Visual Studio: it stopped working and keeps on displaying the message "Microsoft Visual Studio professional has stopped working ... Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available".

What I cannot do:

- I cannot start the debugger because ... it's calling VS 2012 to debug
- I cannot uninstall VS 2012 (same message)
- I cannot reinstall VS 2012 from its original CD (same message)
- I cannot even do that in safe mode (after forcing the restart of Windows Installer Service)

What I did:

- google for similar problems
- cleaned the registry, etc.
- check the application log, noticing this error:

  - Faulting application name: vs_professional.exe, version: 11.0.50727.1, time stamp: 0x4fd9f28c
  - Faulting module name: igdumd32.dll, version: 9.17.10.2932, time stamp: 0x50c92441
  - Exception code: 0xc0000005
  - Fault offset: 0x0001a56a
  - Faulting process ID: 0x1988
  - Faulting application start time: 0x01ce35224e886a32
  - Faulting    application path: C:\vs\vs_professional.exe
  - Faulting module path:    C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\igdumd32.dll

What I still did not do:

- make a fresh installation of Windows 8 (or 7)

I hope someone could give me an idea ...

PS: Windows 7 was En-US, while Windows 8 is En-En. One would say there is no reason for this to have an impact ... but ... who knows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a graphics driver issue.

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/009caf88-c752-4af9-b83a-665b48520fa4), [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/33936443-529e-4b97-8cbc-0b18edbc7e52/) and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/systemcenterservicemanager/thread/af32509d-e7a6-4288-8558-695857228820).

A couple of suggested solutions from those pages:

1. Update your graphics drivers
2. [DisableHWAcceleration = 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx) (useful if you can't update your drivers for some reason)
3. Rollback to a previous driver version (or in your case uninstall and reinstall with an older version)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I was not able to check it as my driver updater (that comes with my lenovo laptop) cannot be updated from W7 to W8!!! I think I'll go for a fresh installation of Windows 7 ....

Comment: Ah, that does sound like a driver problem then!

Comment: @PhilippeGrondier Might be worth mentioning your exact version of laptop so others can find this answer

Comment: I had this same problem as well trying to install VS 2013 on Windows 10 in a VirtualBox VM. I had to disable the graphics driver (guest additions) in order to install. Thanks for the help.